# How do I use pexp correctly to find a probability in R?

Tags: r, probability

I'm trying to find the probability for the random variable X less than 50 using pexp. My rate is .2.

So I'm trying to compute P(X<50)

I'm struggling to use the proper syntax for this instruction. So far I have:

```
pexp(q=50, rate = .2)
```

I have read articles saying I can use lower.tail and log.p, but I am not sure how to use these to find a probability less than a value. Is there any help I can get for this?

Comment: if you look at the help page for `?pexp` you will see that the default is `lower.tail=TRUE` which calculates  `P[X ≤ x]`. So your code is okay

Comment: You have the correct command. For example, `pexp(50, 0.2, lower.tail = FALSE)` would be for P(X > 50). Try generating, say, 10M random exponential variates with rate = 0.2: `mean(rexp(1e7, 0.2) < 50)`. It should give something close to 0.9999546.